# How to install Apache Mesos / Marathon on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apache-mesos

I would like to install Apache Mesos 1.0.0+ and Marathon ideally from a repository without building the package from source.
I am following the following guide from Mesosphere: https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/ which notes that Ubuntu 16.04 is a supported distribution.

However after running `sudo apt-get -y install marathon` I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  marathon
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 47 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/8,339 kB of archives.
After this operation, 92.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
E: Archive is too short
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/marathon_1.3.0-1.0.506.ubuntu1604_amd64.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 62764 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../marathon_1.3.0-1.0.506.ubuntu1604_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking marathon (1.3.0-1.0.506.ubuntu1604) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/var/cache/apt/archives/marathon_1.3.0-1.0.506.ubuntu1604_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/marathon_1.3.0-1.0.506.ubuntu1604_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/bin/marathon' to '/usr/bin/marathon.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/marathon_1.3.0-1.0.506.ubuntu1604_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is the simplest way to install Mesos on Ubuntu 16.04? I've looked at DC/OS however it does not support Ubuntu.

Comment: Looks like your hardware or OS might be having some issues, the installer works fine here in a fresh vm.

Comment: This was a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 in a KVM machine. Did it work for you in Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.04?

Comment: I think it was actually a 15.04 vm, old provisioning profile

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was bing tracked in GitHub and has been resolved. 
https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/4391#issuecomment-247967413